# Trouble with updating database data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm having trouble with my `UPDATE` statement in which I'm trying to update table data through `WHERE` clause, which gives me error of data miss-match.

```
sqL = "UPDATE Customer SET name= '" & txtName.Text & "', adress= '" & txtAdress.Text & "', contact = '" & txtContact.Text & "' WHERE Customer_ID = '" & txtCustomerID.Text & "'"
```

I've also tried

```
sqL = "UPDATE Customer SET name= '" & txtName.Text & "', adress= '" & txtAdress.Text & "', contact = '" & txtContact.Text & "' WHERE Customer_ID = '" & Convert.ToInt32(txtCustomerID.Text) & "'"
```

with no luck.

Comment: your question is also causing trouble for us, specify the error clearly

Comment: Are you sure that Customer_ID is a string in the database not an integer?

Comment: Please try to make your question readable as well.

Comment: I see your spelling of column names and variables is as bad as the text in your question: `adress` (instead of `address`) and `txtAdress` (instead of `txtAddress`)

Comment: @Bohemian: Good pick but not sure if he has same spelling mistake in the database column.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? What is the exact error message and what is the definition (`create table`) of the `Customer`  table?

Comment: @Kat he's updating a column called `adress`: `', adress= '" & txtAdress.Text`

Answer (score 2):

Please use a parameterised query which is much cleaner and safer:

If you are on c#:

```
string sql = "UPDATE Customer SET name= @name, adress=@address, contact = @contact" +
             " WHERE Customer_ID = @id";
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("yourConnectionString"))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",txtName.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address",txtAdress.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact",txtContact.Text);

   /*
     NOTE: Make sure Textbox value is convertible to Customer_ID data type 
           before executing the  query. It should be done before the using statement.
           Use string.Trim() method to remove any space characters at start/end
   */
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",txtCustomerID.Text.Trim());

   conn.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data type of Customer_ID is an int.  In that case, remove the single quotes from around your convert statement.

```
sqL = "UPDATE Customer SET name= '" & txtName.Text & "', adress= '" & txtAdress.Text & "', contact = '" & txtContact.Text & "' WHERE Customer_ID = " & Convert.ToInt32(txtCustomerID.Text)
```

But do double check the data type in your table to be sure.

Comment: I don't know of any databases that would have any problem with this. They just automatically cast the text to int.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will not compile :-

> The string concatenation operator in C# is plus sign not ampersand.

however as `kaf` advised always use parametrized queries.
[image]

Try using plus sign  instead of an ampersand.

```
 "UPDATE Customer SET name= '" + txtName.Text + "', adress= '" + txtAdress.Text + "', contact = '" + txtContact.Text + "' WHERE Customer_ID = '" + txtCustomerID.Text + "'"
```

If customer ID is int ,convert it to int .